# rviz2 not showing images since update - probable QoS

Tags: ros, rviz, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ran a system update of my Ubuntu 20.04 today. Since then I can not see image topics in rviz2 like before. I assume it is an QoS issue, but I can not solve it.

My rviz version should be

```
$sudo apt list --installed | grep rviz2
ros-foxy-rviz2/focal,now 8.2.4-1focal.20211006.001624 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

The two image topics have the frame IDs (from the realsense_ros2 node)
camera_infra1_optical_frame
camera_depth_optical_frame

If I replay my bag the usual way with `ros2 bag play -l ~/tmp/rviz_issue` I do not see anything with `rviz2` or with `ros2 run rqt_image_view rqt_image_view`.

I tried running the replay with `ros2 bag play -l ~/tmp/rviz_issue --qos-profile-overrides-path ~/tmp/reliability_override.yaml` then I at least get iamges with the `rqt_image_view`

The image topics have the QoS:

```
$ ros2 topic info /camera/infra1/image_rect_raw --verbose
Type: sensor_msgs/msg/Image

Publisher count: 1

Node name: _ros2cli_rosbag2
Node namespace: /
Topic type: sensor_msgs/msg/Image
Endpoint type: PUBLISHER
GID: 01.0f.bd.21.1d.26.00.00.01.00.00.00.00.00.12.03.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00
QoS profile:
  Reliability: RMW_QOS_POLICY_RELIABILITY_BEST_EFFORT
  Durability: RMW_QOS_POLICY_DURABILITY_VOLATILE
  Lifespan: 2147483651294967295 nanoseconds
  Deadline: 2147483651294967295 nanoseconds
  Liveliness: RMW_QOS_POLICY_LIVELINESS_AUTOMATIC
  Liveliness lease duration: 2147483651294967295 nanoseconds

Subscription count: 0

$ ros2 topic info /camera/depth/image_rect_raw --verbose
Type: sensor_msgs/msg/Image

Publisher count: 1

Node name: _ros2cli_rosbag2
Node namespace: /
Topic type: sensor_msgs/msg/Image
Endpoint type: PUBLISHER
GID: 01.0f.bd.21.1d.26.00.00.01.00.00.00.00.00.13.03.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00
QoS profile:
  Reliability: RMW_QOS_POLICY_RELIABILITY_BEST_EFFORT
  Durability: RMW_QOS_POLICY_DURABILITY_VOLATILE
  Lifespan: 2147483651294967295 nanoseconds
  Deadline: 2147483651294967295 nanoseconds
  Liveliness: RMW_QOS_POLICY_LIVELINESS_AUTOMATIC
  Liveliness lease duration: 2147483651294967295 nanoseconds

Subscription count: 0
```

Rviz2 is configured

```
- Class: rviz_default_plugins/Image
  Enabled: true
  Max Value: 1
  Median window: 5
  Min Value: 0
  Name: Image
  Normalize Range: true
  Topic:
    Depth: 5
    Durability Policy: Volatile
    History Policy: Keep Last
    Reliability Policy: Best Effort
    Value: /camera/infra1/image_rect_raw
  Value: true
- Class: rviz_default_plugins/Image
  Enabled: true
  Max Value: 1
  Median window: 5
  Min Value: 0
  Name: Image
  Normalize Range: true
  Topic:
    Depth: 5
    Durability Policy: Volatile
    History Policy: Keep Last
    Reliability Policy: Best Effort
    Value: /camera/depth/image_rect_raw
```

It there an issue with rviz2 since the update or can I fix this by some configuration update. According to [the specs](https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Concepts/About-Quality-of-Service-Settings.html) I can not find an issue with my config.

Unfortunately I can not add a minimal ros2 bag and the config files here. But feel free to ask for more information.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/388482/rviz2-not-showing-images-since-update---probable-qos/) by [basti.hunter](https://answers.ros.org/users/28078/basti.hunter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2021-10-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PatoInso](https://answers.ros.org/users/71833/patoinso/) on 2021-10-12**:
I got a very similar issue with my laserscan data that I can"t see anymore in rviz2 since I did the Foxy update... Can you still see your laser data ?

**Comment by [PatoInso](https://answers.ros.org/users/71833/patoinso/) on 2021-10-12**:
I note I can't also received maps data (map and costmaps)
(I'm using Cyclone DDS)

**Comment by [basti.hunter](https://answers.ros.org/users/28078/basti.hunter/) on 2021-10-12**:
I am not working with laser data, so I can not comment on that. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This seems due to a regression in Rviz2: https://github.com/ros2/rviz/issues/782
I could get a functional Rviz again by following the suggestion and rebuilding version 8.2.3 for Foxy from sources (until the patched version got released):

```
git clone https://github.com/ros2/rviz.git
git checkout tags/8.2.3 -b foxy 

>> In rviz_default_plugins/CMakeLists.txt comment tests lines 491-500 (point_cloud2_display_test) and lines 513-520 (point_cloud_scalar_display_test) that are likely to make the build fail

colcon build
```

---

Originally posted by [PatoInso](https://answers.ros.org/users/71833/patoinso/) with karma: 109 on 2021-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [basti.hunter](https://answers.ros.org/users/28078/basti.hunter/) on 2021-10-12**:
Confirmation on the fix. Worked! Thanks!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-10-12**:
Pedantic, but this is a work-around of course.

The real fix would be to get the regression resolved.

@PatoInso: is there any news about a release which would include a fix?

**Comment by [PatoInso](https://answers.ros.org/users/71833/patoinso/) on 2021-10-12**:
@gvdhoorn No idea, I guess we must keep an eye on the update on the github issue...